# apt preference pinning file with comment does not work in Debian 11 Bullseye: "no Package header"

Tags: debian, apt

I get the following error with `apt` operations on Debian 11:

```
E:Invalid record in the preferences file /etc/apt/preferences.d/filename.pref, no Package header
```

Whereas the referenced file looks like this:

```
// Custom rule
Package: some-package
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 100
```

This pin worked in Debian 9 and Debian 10 flawlessly, but with Debian 11 Bullseye it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian 11, comments in preferences files must start with `#`, `//` is not allowed. Change the file to:

```
# Custom rule
Package: some-package
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 100
```